# does statically compiling php pecl extensions (inside binary vs. extension=ext.so) improve performance?

Tags: php, static, compilation, pecl

does compiling pecl extensions inside the php binary improve performance?

i hope my terminology is right, but:

http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.static.php

thats what i mean.

we have a small set of extensions that are used in pretty much every script execution and were thinking it would just be wiser to have them inside the mod_php binary rather then  loaded via extension=ext.so @ php.d / php.ini. further more we do use a self-compiled php binary rather then a package (rpm/dpg/etc) based one. so doing this would be fairly trivial.

anyone?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Even for old fashioned CGI, I'd expect that the dynamically linked version would be very slightly faster - assuming that you've got a continuous stream of requests - new instances of the interpreter would get [COWed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write). The only time the statically linked approach would be faster (and then its just reducing latency) would be if there are no instances in memory.

OTOH for fastCGI / module, the code just forks - it never goes out of memory.

But, regardless, the difference would be so small its not worth considering (switching away from CGI would give massively more performance improvements)